# How to pass data between react embeddable widgets using redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, widget

I have two widgets called **"search widget"** and **"Name Widget"**, and I build those widget using **webpack**. I want to pass data from search widget to name widget. This is not like passing data from one component to another component. Below image shows that widgets.

[image]

This is the script tags I used.

[image]

action.js

```
export const addReminder = text => ({
    type : "ADD_REMINDER",
    payload : text
});
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
   reminders : []
};

const nameReducer = (state = initialState , action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_REMINDER':
        console.log("Name reducer action - ",action.payload);
        return {
            ...state,
            reminders: [...state.reminders, action.payload]
        }
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

export default nameReducer;
```

store.js

```
import nameReducer from '../reducers/nameReducer';
import { createStore} from 'redux';

const store = createStore(
   nameReducer,
   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

search component code

```
import { addReminder } from '../Redux/actions/nameAction';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class searchComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        name: '',
    };
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.addReminder(this.state.name);
    console.log("this is the form text", this.props.reminders);

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
          <form>
            <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} />
            <br/><br/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={e => {this.onSubmit(e)}}>Submit</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  reminders: state.reminders
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addReminder})(searchComponent);
```

name component code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class nameComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.reminders}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   reminders: state.reminders
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(nameComponent);
```

What I want is, when I enter something in search component and press submit button, the search value must display in the name component. But in the name component **this.props.reminders** didn't get any result. Do I need to pass variable in the script tag or How can I pass data from one widget to another widget?

Comment: do you provide the same redux store to both of your components? Was redux store changed after dispatching?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same redux store. Is it bad?

Comment: in the browser, redux extension shows my state is updated. So redux store is changing after dispatching.

Comment: Using the same redux store is correct. I meant both of your components have one parent with Provider and store there?

Comment: No. For those component I used two providers and importing the same store. `ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Search />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('widget:search'), 
);`    this is the search widget one and for the name widget also I used this.

Comment: I see. I guess your stores have the same structure but not the equal as javascript objects. They have different links. You need somehow share it between components. Just try move your store variable to window scope

Comment: yes. it has different link for each one of these widgets. those bundles came from different widgets. that is needed to each one of these widget. My requirement is to build widget for different websites. so, for one of the website need only one bundle pack. that is why I have different links in script tags.

Comment: Do I need to add some plugins to webpack.config.js file?

Comment: Refer the document https://builditmasters.com/build-react-embeddable-widgets-using-webpack/